# How to add delay between the movement of two disks

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl

I'm currently doing an assignment in OpenGL and what I'm supposed to do is make two disks and then as I move the cursor on the screen and click the two disks should move to that position where I click on the window but the trick is that both the disks should not move together. The first disk should move and then after a small delay the second disk should move. Now I have been able to make both the disks move together at the point I click. What I want to know is how am I supposed to add a delay in the movement of both the disks. Please help!
This is my current code. Thanks!

EDIT: 
Here's my updated code after implementing exactly what you said and now none of the disks are moving. If you understand the problem, fine otherwise thanks for all the help :)

```
#include <math.h>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <glut.h>

typedef struct _Vector
{
    double x,y,z;
} Vector;

const int W_SCREEN = 1366;
const int H_SCREEN = 768;
const double PI = 3.14159265;
GLUquadric *qobja;
double speed = 10;
double radian;
double rot;
Vector pos2;
Vector pos;
Vector vel;
Vector dis;
Vector dir;
Vector mousecoords;

void mouse(int button, int state, int x , int y)
{
    mousecoords.x = x - W_SCREEN/2;
    mousecoords.y = -y + H_SCREEN/2;
}

void move()
{
    dis.x = mousecoords.x - pos.x;
    dis.y = mousecoords.y - pos.y;
    if(sqrt(dis.x*dis.x + dis.y*dis.y) < speed)
    {
        pos.x = mousecoords.x;
        pos.y = mousecoords.y;
        pos2.x = mousecoords.x;
        pos2.y = mousecoords.y;
    }
    else
    {
        radian = atan2(dis.y,dis.x);
        pos.x += cos(radian)*speed;
        pos.y += sin(radian)*speed;
        pos2.x += cos(radian)*speed;
        pos2.y += sin(radian)*speed;
    }
}

void moveSecondDisk(int value)
{
    // Code that moves (updates coordinates) of second disk
    move();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void moveFirstDisk(int value)
{
    // Code that moves (updates coordinates) of first disk
    move();
    glutPostRedisplay();
    unsigned int secondDiskDelay = 5000;
    glutTimerFunc(secondDiskDelay, moveSecondDisk, 0);
}

void display(void)
{
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(-W_SCREEN/2,W_SCREEN/2,-H_SCREEN/2,H_SCREEN/2,-100,100);
    qobja = gluNewQuadric();
    gluQuadricNormals(qobja, GLU_SMOOTH);
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,25,50,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos2.x,pos2.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,50.5,65,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    /*glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,65.5,80,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,80.5,90,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,90.5,100,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,100.5,110,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,110.5,120,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,120.5,130,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,130.5,140,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,140.5,150,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,150.5,160,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();
    glPushMatrix();
    glColor3f(0,0,0);
    glTranslated(pos.x,pos.y,0);
    gluCylinder(qobja,160.5,170,0,100,100);
    glPopMatrix();*/
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void init(void)
{
    glutInitDisplayMode(GLUT_DOUBLE | GLUT_RGB | GLUT_DEPTH);
    glutInitWindowSize(W_SCREEN,H_SCREEN);
    glutCreateWindow("ORCA WHALE SIMULATION");
    glutDisplayFunc(display);
    glutMouseFunc(mouse);
    unsigned int firstDiskDelay = 2000;
    glutTimerFunc(firstDiskDelay, moveFirstDisk, 0);
    glClearColor(1,1,1,1);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    glutInit(&argc, argv);
    init();
    glutMainLoop();
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: Well? Did you manage to solve the problem?

Comment: No, they are all still moving together :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a timer to accomplish this. Create a function that moves the second disk with the following signature:

```
void moveSecondDisk(int value);
```

Then, execute the code that moves the first disk. Finally, call function `glutTimerFunc`, passing it the function `moveSecondDisk` as callback (second parameter). The first parameter will be delay between moving of two discs (expressed in miliseconds), and the third one will be value that is passed the callback function. Note that you can pass complex data to callback function by passing a pointer to a complex structure (or an object) as an integer, then casting it back to the desired type in the callback function. For more info, check the following links:

https://www.opengl.org/resources/libraries/glut/spec3/node64.html

https://www.opengl.org/discussion_boards/showthread.php/170990-glutTimerFunc

EDIT:
A more detailed explanation:

```
void movePos()
{
    // Code that only modifies pos
    ...
}

void movePos2()
{
    // Code that only modifies pos2
    ...
}

void moveSecondDisk(int value)
{
    movePos2();
    glutPostRedisplay();
}

void moveFirstDisk(int value)
{
    movePos();
    glutPostRedisplay();

    unsigned int secondDiskDelay = 200;
    glutTimerFunc(secondDiskDelay, moveSecondDisk, 0);
    glutTimerFunc(300, moveFirstDisk, 0);
}

void init()
{
    ...
    unsigned int firstDiskDelay = 50;
    glutTimerFunc(firstDiskDelay, moveFirstDisk, 0);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still not getting it. Can you kindly show it in my code? :/

Comment: @FahadCheema I see that you are passing `25` as first parameter to `glutTimerFunc`. As I said before, this delay is expressed in miliseconds. This is the reason why it seems that they are moving at the same time. Increase the delay to 5000 miliseconds (5 seconds) and then see what happens.

Comment: Thanks for the help Marko but it still isn't working :(

Comment: Bsically you're saying this right?
First make a function
`void moveSecondDisk(int value)
{
move();
glutTimerFunc(5000,moveSecondDisk,0);
}`
And then after I make the first disk in display function I call glutTimerFunc with value 1000?

Comment: @FahadCheema No! I am talking about the delay of `25` when you are calling `glutTimerFunc` for the first time (inside function `init`). Call it like this `glutTimerFunc(5000,update,0)`.

Comment: @FahadCheema I've updated my answer. This is how you do it. If this does not work, then you are accidentally changing the coordinates of both disks at the same time. I think the problem is with calls to `glTranslated`. You update `pos.x` and `pos.y` when moving first disk, and then you use these values to specify the position of second disk. Try using a second vector (for example, named `pos2`) for the position of the second disk.

Comment: Did exactly as you said and now not even a single disk is moving. I've added the updated code after implementing your solution. This is what you meant, right? Take a look :)
Really appreciate your help mate!

Comment: @FahadCheema It does not work because I overlooked one `glutTimerFunc` call. However, you are once again modifying both disk positions at once when function `move` is called. You need to split it into two functions, one that modifies `pos`, and one that modifies `pos2`. I will edit my answer once more, I hope you will understand it this time.

Comment: One last thing. How will I modify this to make it work for a multiple number of disks i.e 4 or 5 disks?

Comment: Actually what I'm trying to make is this using disks
'http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/5/3970/3970473_sprite198.swf'

Comment: @FahadCheema Well you just generalize the approach above. Each time you move coordinates of a disk, you setup a timer with a callback function that will move coordinates of the next disk. The last callback function just moves the disk and stops. Try to use the example with two disks to implement the case for three. Then try the general case with more disks. Btw, I can't open the link you've given in your comment. Good luck!

Comment: Ok thanks. Here's the link
http://img0.liveinternet.ru/images/attach/c/5/3970/3970473_sprite198.swf

Comment: Is there any better approach to make this thing that I've sent you in the link?

Comment: @FahadCheema Sorry, but to be honest, I do not know. You will have to ask someone who has more experience with openGL. I know some basic stuff, but I'm not a professional.